# What does "сказ" mean?

Tags: значения, английский

Perhaps it is actually 'CKAЭ' rather than 'CKA3'... but either way I can't find an answer through Google.

I'm referring to what is shown on this piece of Russian Constructivist artwork.

Can anyone shed any light on what it might mean?

[image]

Comment: translating text from pictures or book titles is off-topic here however in this particular case it's "супрематический сказ" - where сказ is a form of folklore narrative - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skaz - so it's sort of "Supremativistic tale of two squares". Or "suprematic" - don't know the right word, but you got the idea.

Comment: See [on Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Lissitzky). The suprematic **tale** about two squares.

Comment: amazing, thank you both!